# Magento : Different Tax Based On Shipping State

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, price, tax

I want set different tax for different state based on customer shipping address state.

I have added Tax class from admin for different tax and it's working. but I want product price should not change.

If the product price is 100 (incl. tax) than tax should be deducted from the base price. Means for state 1 if the tax is 10% product price should be 90(excl. tax) and 10 for tax. For state 2 if tax is 5% then price should be 95 and 5 for tax.

Can Any One Have Idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, Magento allows this out of the box.

Under *System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Tax -> Calculation Settings*, you can set *Catalog Prices* to *Including Tax*.

This means that prices that you assign to products already include tax. Magento will than calculation tax amount based on products tax class. For different tax rates tax amount will be different, but price including tax will always be same.